# Update Centos without upgrading kernel or OS

Tags: security, version-control

I tried to find answers to this issue but I am having a hard time to find the right keywords.

So here is my issue.
Dongled mini PC with some itchy software when it comes to patching the system.
Is it possible to get updates only for a specific release and kernel version even if a newer OS is available?

I have CentOS 7.5 18.04 running here and have been told that system will be upgraded automatically if a newer OS is available.
Security patches for "older" OS are only available as RedHat for paying users.

Is it possible to upgrade to the latest and greatest (security) mitigating a leap to newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have CentOS 7.5 18.04 running here and have been told that system
>   will be upgraded automatically if a newer OS is available

There is no automatic update of the installed packages, unless `yum-cron` is configured for auto-update !

Keeping the current kernel "patch update level" : Exclude all kernel* packages in `/etc/yum.conf` : Add a text line ...

```
exclude kernel*
```

Note : The wild-card ( * ) is important.

Note 2 : The kernel version doesn't change at update. The "patching level numbering" does. Current is `kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7`. You can update to latest with `# yum install kernel`

Note 3 : No update will change OS. It's still CentOS 7. The "Update level numbering" can change : Current is "7.6.1810".

**Old updates** for CentOS 7.5 18.04 http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Automatic update was meant like update level changing.
The URL you have at the end is actually what I was looking for.
Cheers mate :)